# Variables Window Switching to Debug Window while Debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I am trying to run a nested for loop in java in Eclipse IDE (Oxygen) and to check the flow I have added two breakpoints on each of the for loop. And when I debug, I am checking the values in 'Variables' window but as soon as I click on to step into (F5) or Step over (F6) button my window is switching from Variables window to Debug Window and then I have to switch to Variables window again for each iteration. This is a little annoying. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could click on the Variables tab, the nub at the top of the view, and drag it into its own frame so that both views appear at the same time within the Eclipse window.  This way the behavior of the Debug view does not interfere with the Variables view.  Eclipse will guide you with what the current drag position will do with outlines drawn over the window.

This outline shows a new frame would be created.

[image: Outlines separating Variables into new frame]

This outline shows moving the view into an existing frame together through the green bar.

[image: Outline dropping Variables into existing frame]

You could also drag the Variables tab outside the Eclipse window so that the view has its own window.  To return the Variables window to the Eclipse window layout, drag the tab back into the Eclipse window.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked, now I am able to view both the windows separately.